# Getting winerror 3 filenotfounderror in basicsr\\archs after generating exe file by pyinstaller in python

Tags: python, pyinstaller, scandir, filenotfounderror

I'm using BasicSR in my one of the desktop application.
and It's working and running fine on PyCharm.

But after converting it to EXE file using pyinstaller, I'm getting below error.

I think it can be os.scandir, but how can I solve this, I don't know..

please help me to resolve this as I've already spent a lot time..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "yogeshbhaiDesktop.py", line 7, in
File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 671, in load_unlocked
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
File "basicsr_init.py", line 3, in
File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "", line 975, in find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 671, in load_unlocked
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
File "basicsr\archs_init.py", line 14, in
File "basicsr\archs_init.py", line 14, in
File "basicsr\utils\misc.py", line 74, in _scandir
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Users\gbd\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI45162\basicsr\archs'
```

.spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['yogeshbhaiDesktop.py'],
             pathex=['E:\\deployyPythonDesktop'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=['hook-basicsr.py'],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='yogeshbhaiDesktop',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

hook-basicsr.py file

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files("basicsr", includes=["archs/*_arch.py"])
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you have a bundling problem then the place to fix it is your `.spec` file.  You're not showing us the `.spec` file. The `pyinstaller` docs have a very helpful section called *When things go wrong.* Start by working through it.

Comment: okk, I edited this post and added `.spec` file and `hook-basicsr.py` files.
I hooked path with `hook-basicsr.py` file but still it is not working..

Comment: Going solely on the names of the modules in the stack trace, this looks like what `pyinstaller` calls a *hidden import*. But you are going to have to work through the `pyinstaller` log (which can often be long enough to make anyone's heart sink) to be sure. Problems like this tend to be one-of-a-kind and so it is hard to give advice that is any more specific.

Comment: I tried many solutions, I've posted this issue on github also(on 2-3 projects like pyinstaller, basicsr..)

Still not able to reach out to the solution.

So, now I'm decided to stop wasting my time, and now I'll install python and all packages on every computers and then run this desktop file using .bat file..


Thanks all of you for your findings and supports..

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by replacing the content of `basicsr/archs/__init__.py` with the following.
And do the same operation for those who use scandir in `__init__.py`.

```py
import importlib
from copy import deepcopy
from os import path as osp

from basicsr.utils import get_root_logger, scandir
from basicsr.utils.registry import ARCH_REGISTRY

__all__ = ['build_network']

# automatically scan and import arch modules for registry
# scan all the files under the 'archs' folder and collect files ending with
# '_arch.py'
# arch_folder = osp.dirname(osp.abspath(__file__))
# arch_filenames = [osp.splitext(osp.basename(v))[0] for v in scandir(arch_folder) if v.endswith('_arch.py')]
# # import all the arch modules
# _arch_modules = [importlib.import_module(f'basicsr.archs.{file_name}') for file_name in arch_filenames]

from . import basicvsrpp_arch
from . import basicvsr_arch
from . import dfdnet_arch
from . import discriminator_arch
from . import duf_arch
from . import ecbsr_arch
from . import edsr_arch
from . import edvr_arch
from . import hifacegan_arch
from . import rcan_arch
from . import ridnet_arch
from . import rrdbnet_arch
from . import spynet_arch
from . import srresnet_arch
from . import srvgg_arch
from . import stylegan2_arch
from . import swinir_arch
from . import tof_arch
from . import vgg_arch

def build_network(opt):
    opt = deepcopy(opt)
    network_type = opt.pop('type')
    net = ARCH_REGISTRY.get(network_type)(**opt)
    logger = get_root_logger()
    logger.info(f'Network [{net.__class__.__name__}] is created.')
    return net
```